# Can an XNA Silverlight app run on the Xbox 360?

Tags: silverlight, xna, xbox360

The XNA Game Studio 4.0 introduced Silverlight as a supported project type. It seems like XNA studio is quite cross-platform. But there's nothing that says that my Xbox 360 game can use Silverlight UI. For my planned game, Silverlight would be fine. We don't need rich 3D graphics. But *is it possible?*

Comment: It might be a good idea to cross post this on the game development stack exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/65897.aspx
Silverlight does not exist on the XBox360 as of XNA Game Studio 4.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

(For starters - how would you do input on the 360? There's no mouse or touch input!)

To demonstrate: If you look at the "Silverlight" version pages on the MSDN you can see icons for "Supported by Silverlight for Windows Phone" and "Supported by Xbox 360".

So if I look up part of the core framework, like [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5(v=VS.95).aspx), I can see which methods are supported on both platforms (most of them - and the Windows Phone and Xbox 360 have the same support).

Now if I look up something Silverlight-specific, like [System.Windows.Media.Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush(v=VS.95).aspx), I can see that its methods are only supported by Windows Phone - not by the Xbox 360.

(On the .NET 3.0, 3.5 and 4 pages there is a "Supported by the XNA Framework" icon. I'm pretty sure these are for XNA 3.1 on the Xbox 360.)

Comment: Silverlight doesn't require Touch- or Mouse-only interfaces. Keyboard works too. But yeah, I noticed that it looks like the MSDN docs need to be updated for XNA4 and the various framework references need to be either unified and then filterable based on the target platform. But this is still supposition. XNA developers have blogged/twittered about silverlight running on the 360, and some of the advertisement and promo apps are Silverlight-based.

Comment: @Eric I cannot find any sources for this - aside from the vague mid-2009 announcement that Silverlight might be coming for *advertising* on the Xbox 360 in the future. What I did find was Nick Gravelyn saying "Silverlight does not exist on the Xbox 360, so no, you cannot make an XBLIG using Silverlight." http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/65897.aspx - although I suspect you already know, seeing as it's a response to *your* question.

Comment: Yup. that question hadn't been answered yet, so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight and XNA can't be mixed. The Xbox 360 will only run XNA applications. The introduction of Silverlight project is for Windows Phone 7 development.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently introduced silverlight on xbox 360

Comment: You should include an offical link or additional information.

Comment: Yes please! Is it released yet? or just announced?

Answer (score 0):

Their is internet explorer for xbox coming and some updates which might provide flash and/or silverlight support later but as far as i know nothing right now.